# Setting up google project for authentication api

Tags: google-api, django-allauth

I am trying to set up google authentication for my local project. I run projects in python virtual environments and have different local domainnames set up for those. Names like projectname.dev. When i enter http://projectname.dev in browser the site opens up.

When i went to https://console.developers.google.com/project/< myprojectid >/apiui/credential?authuser=0 i could set values like javascript origin and authorized redirect uri there. I set javascript origins to http://projectname.dev and tried to put same domain for authorized redirect url too, but it did not work and i had to leave it to localhost.

When i tried to authenticate via django-allauth, i got such response from google:

```
**Error: invalid_request**

Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Non-public domains not allowed: http://projectname.dev/account/google/login/callback/
```

Now my questions are:

- Can i develop this part of project locally with domainname like projectname.dev or do i need to set it up for localhost? Will local redirect from localhost -> projectname.dev work?
- If i can do it with projectname.dev, then perhaps there is an error in the way i have this project set up in google developers console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any case, if you cannot set the redirect URI in the Cloud Console, Google will throw you our when you try to authorize the app.

My recommendation would be to choose either of those solutions :

- Use "localhost" as you said, with some kind of redirection/NAT/proxy to projectname.dev
- Replace projectname.dev with a domain with an actual tld such as projectname.thisdomaindoesnotexist.com . Then configure this domain name to map to your servers.

Or wait for ".dev" to be recognized as an actual TLD, and you'll be good :)

Comment: Actually, it looks like you can now enter domains like projectname.dev into google client setup. NICE!